# Is the lack of a comma here correct?

Tags: commas

I am reading a paper and was confused about how exactly the commas should be used in the following phrase:

> Additionally, if the sensor is housed in a metal pod the readings can be near useless.

Does it make more sense to place a comma after "pod"? Like so:

> Additionally, if the sensor is housed in a metal pod, the readings can be near useless.

Comment: Commas are best used only to avoid ambiguity and to aid in readability. And these are sometimes debatable; so there is no right or wrong answer except: use your judgment. And if you don't trust your judgment, consult a **style guide**. Note that this website is not mean to serve as an interactive style guide. Last, there are hundreds of questions on this site and on the wider web that address this question. Please do some research before asking here. I ask this nicely. Last, consult a style guide before asking here. I also ask this nicely. Thanks and have a super super day.